# problem to install yii2 advanced template

Tags: yii2

I need some help with my Yii2 instalation, when i execute:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii2advanced
```

I got this:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs> composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii2advanced
Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.16)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.16): Loading from cache
Created project in yii2advanced
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for codeception/verify ~1.0.0 -> satisfiable by codeception/verify[1.0.0].
    - codeception/verify 1.0.0 requires php >= 7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.9 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.8 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.7 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.6 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.13 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.12 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.11 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.10 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~6.5.5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.5.10, 6.5.11, 6.5.12, 6.5.13, 6.5.14, 6.5.5, 6.5.6, 6.5.7, 6.5.8, 6.5.9].

PS C:\xampp\htdocs>
```

I have not problem with the basic template.

Does now advanced app need php 7?.
How can I install it without php 7?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Developers accidentally added `"phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.5"` to composer which has a requirement of `"php: ^7.0"`.

U can try to add `--ignore-platform-reqs`

`composer create-project --prefer-dist --ignore-platform-reqs yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii2advanced`

or

Add fake php using `composer config -g -e` to edit

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform":{
            "php":"7.0"
        }
    }
}
```